# The code skips a command in Python. Can anyone tell me why?

Tags: python, macos, macos-catalina

So, basically, I was just coding so that if you write a game's name, it opens it.

```
print('You can play games here!')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Snake')
time.sleep(0.5)
print('Maze')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Type the name of one of the games to open it!')

game = input()

if game == 'Snake':
        import Snake
else:
    if game == 'Maze':
            import Maze

print('This Program Is Still In Development')
```

When I choose "Snake", it works perfectly. But when I choose "Maze", it just skips to the `print('This Program Is Still In Development')` part.

Can anyone help, please? I am on MAC OS X btw

EDIT: If I do `elif`, it doesn't change. Neither does a function. For some reason the only game that works is Snake.

EDIT 2: The weird thing is that when I just open Maze.py separately, IT WORKS. HOW?

Comment: Is anything visible supposed to happen when you `import Maze`? (btw, the convention is to use lowercase for module names in Python)

Comment: import Maze opens a new game in Terminal. Like, when I type "Maze", it should open the game

Comment: I think that your program doesn't skip anything, simply you have to check what the `Maze` module does... BTW dunno if it's only the snippet but i see some indentation leak there

Comment: Can we see the Maze.py module then? By the way,

Comment: I'd suggest to import all modules at the top of the file and create main functions (for example `main()` or `run()`) so you can do `Maze.main()` instead of  `import Maze`. It will be easier to detect issues with imports this way because all of them will be called at the beginning

Comment: More simply, just create a file with only one line: `import Maze`, and see if anything happens when you run it. It looks like nothing will happen.

Comment: Looks like I hit return too early. Wanted to note that your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: When i just type import Maze, it doesn't do anything

Comment: wdym by indentation, astrochun?

Comment: So the problem is in your `Maze.py` that doesn't do anything visible, not in this part of the code. You should probably delete this question, and look at your Maze module to see what it really executes.

Comment: Thierry Lathuille the weird thing is that when I just open Maze.py separately, IT WORKS. HOW?

Comment: We can't know, that's a completely different question, and you haven't provided any relevant information. Doesn't your `Maze.py` contain an `if __name__ == '__main__':` section? This is meant to be executed only when your module is run directly, and not when imported.

Comment: Thierry Lathuille it turns out there is a if __name__ == '__main__': section. Thx so much!

Answer (score -1):

change this:

```
else:
    if statement:
        # code
```

into this:

```
elif statement:
    # code
```

this works (added `print` to see `its working`):

```py
import time
print('You can play games here!')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Snake')
time.sleep(1.5)
print('Maze')
time.sleep(1.5)

game = input('Type the name of one of the games to open it!')

# lowercase the user input to have less conditions
# and to make sure that we skip conditions because of case sensitivity
game = game.lower()

if game == 'snake':
   # do stuff
   print("snake")

elif game == 'maze':
   # do stuff
   print("maze")

print('This Program Is Still In Development')
```

Comment: Could you care to explain how you think that this would make any difference and solve the OP's problem?

Comment: Not really, but i even tried doing this:

if:
        (code)

if:
        (code)

Comment: I think, in python3 if you don't use "elif", it just runs whatever the condition is. but if you use it, it checks the condition. I tried this and it worked.

Comment: why PRINT??? My script is supposed to open another one, not print a text!

Comment: sorry, because I didn't have Maze or Snake, I tried to print to test it and copied code here

Comment: @SmoggyLeaf,  dont get me wrong, stack overflow is `handling your error` or `bug` not `writing your code`, that part you are handling yourself.